# Antlr4 maven integration errors

Tags: java, maven, parsing, pom.xml, antlr4

I'm trying to generate the correct java files from antlr4 lexers/parsers with maven. My grammars are mostly separated into lexing files and parsing files problem is that I can't manage to generate the .tokens files with maven.
My project looks like this:

```
src/
....main/
........antlr4/
______________MessageParsingGrammar.g4
______________ConfigurationParsingGrammar.g4
..............imports/
______________________MessageLexingGrammar.g4
______________________ConfigurationLexingGrammar.g4

....java/
________main.java
```

In the main.java, I"m using the grammar generated files.
My pom file looks like this:

```
<build>
            <sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>
          <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.antlr</groupId>
                <artifactId>antlr4-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>4.5.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <sourceDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/antlr4</sourceDirectory>
                    <libDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/antlr4/imports</libDirectory>
                    <outputDirectory>${basedir}/src/main/java/antlr4</outputDirectory>
                    <visitor>true</visitor>
                    <listener>true</listener>
                </configuration>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <id>processAntlr</id>
                        <phase>generate-sources</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>antlr4</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>

            <plugin>
            <artifactId>maven-clean-plugin</artifactId>
            <version>2.5</version>
            <configuration>
                <filesets>
                    <fileset>
                        <directory>${basedir}/src/main/java/antlr4</directory>
                    </fileset>
                </filesets>
            </configuration>
        </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
```

I'm not sure what i'm doing wrong. I even tried to move the lexing files the the same folder as the grammar files.

**Update**

I"m using now the defautl generation settings, the code is generated but under a default package so I'm not able to use it
[image]

Comment: First follow conventions which means not to change things like `<sourceDirectory>src</sourceDirectory>` . Than check if the plugin configuration offers good defaults which it does and never generate code into `src/main/`...The default is generating everything into `target/...` folder...

Comment: Is the sourceDirectory for the antlr4 plugin by default not in the ${basedir}/src/main/antlr4 Also, I need to use the generated java file in this same project that's way i'm trying to generate them in the main/java if not what would be the solution?

Comment: The code says something different: `@Parameter(defaultValue = "${basedir}/src/main/antlr4")
    private File sourceDirectory;` ? And the code will automatically being generated into `target/generated-sources/antlr4` and the code will be added to source which means it will be picked up automatically from maven-compiler-plugin... ?

Comment: the code is added to source in a default package, so i can't use the files ( see update )

Comment: You can configure the package name in the grammar file.